How to limit default "yolo" model to recognize less objects?
i want to use default YOLOv8 model (yolov8m.pt) for object detection. I know that default YOLO models uses COCO dataset and can detect 80+ objects. I just want to detect like 5 of them, how can i achieve this?

No, it is incorrect to say "that default YOLO models uses COCO dataset".  Someone out there may have used YOLO and the MSCOCO dataset, then published those pre-trained weights for anyone to download.  But those are not the default.
The "default" is for people to train their own networks.  The MSCOCO pre-trained ones are more along the lines of "what can we provide to new users so they can test things out and see some sort of results once they've installed our framework."

The OP references a .pt file which is a YOLO model trained on the COCO dataset (by default).

To filter the classes in the prediction mode use the classes parameter of the predict function, where you need to specify the relevant classes IDs.

classes,    list[int]. Filters predictions to a set of class IDs. Only detections belonging to the specified classes will be returned. Useful for focusing on relevant objects in multi-class detection tasks. https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#inference-arguments

The class list for the COCO dataset can be found here: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/ultralytics/cfg/datasets/coco.yaml.
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
results = model.predict(source='img.jpg', classes=[0, 3, 5])

